# Mii código de C++ no muestra resultados

Tags: c++, números-primos

Hola y un saludo a toda la comunidad, soy muy nuevo en esto de C++ y resulta que tengo echo este código en C++ que en  teoría debería mostrar el número primo mas cercano al ingresado por el usuario, sin embargo tan solo muestra el mensaje de ingresar y el numero pero de ahí se va al final y no muestra nada, alguna sugerencia por favor? desde ya muchas gracias a todos/as!

```
int n,m,x;
cout<<"Ingrese un valor";
cin>>n;

for (x=2;n;) {
    n=2;
    bool flag=true;     
    while (flag=true) {
        if (x%0==0)
        {
            flag=false;
        }else{
            m=m+1;
        }
    }
    if (flag=true) 
    {
        cout<<"numero primo";
        cout<<x;
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

[image: Numeros Primos Cercanos]

Comment: Por favor, muestra el código **como texto**. Una imagen no se puede copiar/pegar, y hace mucho mas difícil que nadie pueda ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo añadí

Answer (score 0):

El código tiene fallos de lógica y un error que al principio ocurre bastante,y que es confundir el operador de asinación `=` con el de comparación `==`

No me veía en condiciones de corregir tu código, pero te muestro esta solución.

Primero, establecemos una función para saber si un número es primo. La definición es que un número primo sólo es divisible por si mismo y por uno. Entonces recorremos todos los valores posibles entre 2 y el número anterior del que queremos averiguar (descartamos el 1 y el propio numero por motivos obvios) si es primo, y si en algún momento su módulo es 0, ya sabemos que no es primo y salimos de la función:

```
bool esPrimo (int n)
{
    for (int i = 2;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (n%i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Ahora podemos usar la función de esta forma:

```
while (!esPrimo(numeroaaveriguar))
    {
        numeroaaveriguar--;
    }
```

Para hallar el inferior, o

```
while (!esPrimo(numeroaaveriguar))
    {
        numeroaaveriguar++;
    }
```

El código completo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool esPrimo (int n);

int main()
{
    int n, primoinferior,primosuperior;
    cout<<"Ingrese un valor ";
    cin>>n;
    primoinferior = n;
    primosuperior = n;
    while (!esPrimo(primoinferior))
    {
        primoinferior--;
    }
    cout<<"Primo mas cercano inferior "<<primoinferior<<endl;
    while (!esPrimo(primosuperior))
    {
        primosuperior++;
    }
    cout<<"Primo mas cercano superior "<<primosuperior<<endl;
    return 0;
}

bool esPrimo (int n)
{
    for (int i = 2;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (n%i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Si quieres averiguar el primo más cercano, pues sólo has de elegir del inferior o superior el más cercano al número.